# Converting parts of a list from strings to integers in python 3.4

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple Caesar Cypher for a class project, and I can't get past creating the cypher key. So far I have:

```
import sys
ALPHABET = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','']

def main(text, key):
    print("Encoding message '", text,"'with key",key)
    ALPHABET = generate_cypher(key)

def generate_cypher(ckey):
    cypher = []
    for i in ALPHABET:
        x = ALPHABET[i] + ckey
        cypher = cypher + x
    return cypher

main(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
```

I keep getting this error:
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You have a number of problems with your code, no `:` on you function definitions. Indexing with a `str` - `x = i + ckey` would be sufficient. Trying to add a `str` to a list: `cypher.append(x)` would work. Binding a new value to a local `ALPHABET`, which I assume wasn't intended. And ultimately you've not created a cypher key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `for i in ALPHABET` is iterating over the elements in `ALPHABET` not the indices. So its going 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. You want to use `for i in range(len(ALPHABET))` if you want to iterate over the indices.

The error is telling you that `ALPHABET[i]` is failing as `i` is not an integer. In this case the first iteration is the letter `a` so it is trying to do `ALPHABET['a']` which won't work and returns the error. That is why you need to iterate over the indices not the elements.

Assuming ckey is intended to be an integer for the offset of the cypher you can fix you code with the following:

**Credit to @AChampion on a nice little trick for the index length**

```
def generate_cypher(ckey):
    cypher = []
    for i in range(len(ALPHABET)):
        x = ALPHABET[(i+ckey)%len(ALPHABET)]
        cypher.append(x)
    return cypher
```

Notice that I added some logic to fix the situation at the end of your iteration where the index will be beyond the available indices of the list. The cypher needs to wrap around to the beginning at this point thus the necessity of the modulo for ensuring that the index will never be larger than the size of ALPHABET.

Comment: Going to indices is a step backwards, just `x = i + ckey`.

Comment: I've done this and now I'm getting the error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: I take it back, the OP probably intended `ALPHABET[i + ckey]`, so `indices` were correct.

Comment: @PeytonBrakefield Edited answer

Comment: You can use the modulus operator to simplify, `x = ALPHABET[(i+ckey)%len(ALPHABET)]` and remove the conditional logic. (And you still need a `:` at the end of your function definition)

Comment: Thanks for the help, champion and grr, you both helped immensely. I forgot to write in the colons in the code I put on the post, my bad lol.